# SwiftUI - Access List Selection in Another View

Tags: swift, xcode, list, swiftui, swiftui-list

I want to access the list selection in another view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExerciseSelectorView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var exercises: FetchedResults<Exercise>
    @State var selectedItems = Set<Exercise>()
   
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack {
                Button("Add") {
                createExerciseSet()
                }
                List(selection: $selectedItems) {
                    ForEach(exercises, id: \.self) { e in
                        Text(e.exercisename)
                    }
                }
                .environment(\.editMode, .constant(EditMode.active))
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Selected \(selectedItems.count) rows"))
                .toolbar { EditButton() }
                
            }
            
        }
    }
```

I'm pretty sure selectedItems can't be a @State var, but when I set it to Binding, the error is "No exact matches in call to initializer"
When I try to set it to @ObservedObject, the error is "Generic struct 'ObservedObject' requires that 'Set' conform to 'ObservableObject'" So I'm not sure how to handle an array of a class. I just want to be able to use the array of selectedItems in a different view. Thank you in advance!!!!

Below is the second view where I want to use the selectedItems, but I am getting "Cannot find 'selectedItems' in scope"

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExSetView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var exsets: FetchedResults<ExerciseSet>
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(selectedItems) { e in
                    
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: ExSetInputView(selectedItems: e),
                        label: {
                            Text(e.exercise.exercisename)
                        }
                    )}
            }
            
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExSetView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
 FetchedResults<ExerciseSet>
    @State var selectedItems = Set<Exercise>()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
               
                  Text("Set Count: \(selectedItems.count)")
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: just pass `selectedItems` to the "otherview" (that you don't show), just like you would with any other var. It is best to show a minimal reproducible code example, see:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Comment: @workingdog support Ukraine When I do that, the error returned is "Cannot find 'selectedItems' in scope"

Comment: best to edit your question, and paste the code in there properly formated. In the comments it is unreadable. Show a minimal reproducible code, see:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  Show clearly which line has the error, and the full error message.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I edited the question so the code is properly formatted

Comment: The error is telling you that you don't have `selectedItems` in `ExSetView`.
You need to pass `selectedItems` to `ExSetView`,
 using for example: `@State var selectedItems: Set<Exercise>`, then you can pass it
 to `ExSetInputView(selectedItems: e)` (which you don't show).
Show a minimal **reproducible** code, see:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I added `@State var selectedItems: Set<Exercise>` to ExSetView and try to display the count of items in selected items, it is empty. I updated my question to show my change. Do you have any idea what can be causing that? I've tried a lot of different things with no success. Displaying the count in the parent view (selectorView) shows the count, but ExSetView does not.

Comment: From your "new" code, I can see now that you really need a better understanding of the **very basics** of SwiftUI, 
such as, passing data from one view to another. My advice is, 
do the tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/  
There is also a good explanation of how to manage data in your app at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app